# Issue styling the image upload button

Tags: python, html, css, django

Basically I am trying to style my image upload form field. By following guidance from another question from here I ended up doing this:

```js
document.getElementById("uploadBtn").onchange = function () {
            document.getElementById("uploadFile").value = this.value;
        };
```

```css
.fileUpload {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 10px;
  }
  .fileUpload input.upload {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  }
```

```html
<input id="uploadFile" placeholder="Choose File" disabled="disabled"/>
                    <div class="fileUpload btn btn-primary">
                        <span>Upload</span>
                        <input id="uploadBtn" type="file" class="upload"/>
                    </div>
```

This works as it should but how do I bind it to my django form field ? If I replace class attribute inside the input from "upload" to "profile_pic", the main upload button will appear, which is bad. Or am I doing it wrong ? I just need the information to be passed to my form.

```html
photo = forms.ImageField(required=True,
                             widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={'class': 'profile_pic'}))
```

Comment: I am not sure I understood your question. Are you trying to replace the "standard" upload button from the django FileField or only apply style to it ?

Comment: Apply style to it

Comment: Can you paste the HTML generated by the django form?

Comment: It's only what I wrote above